To get IDL of Raydium-CP-Swap (CPMMoo8L3F4NbTegBCKVNunggL7H1ZpdTHKxQB5qKP1C)
I want to get IDL of Raydium-cp-swap(CPMMoo8L3F4NbTegBCKVNunggL7H1ZpdTHKxQB5qKP1C).
I know that is built with Anchor. So I tried
anchor idl fetch CPMMoo8L3F4NbTegBCKVNunggL7H1ZpdTHKxQB5qKP1C

But it didn't work giving err.
Must I do build the source code of that program to get IDL?
Is there any direct & efficient way to get IDL?
Thank you.

Some areas that you'll need to check.

make sure that you are on the correct cluster. CPMMoo8L3F4NbTegBCKVNunggL7H1ZpdTHKxQB5qKP1C is the program address on mainnet and CPMDWBwJDtYax9qW7AyRuVC19Cc4L4Vcy4n2BHAbHkCW on devnet

To change to mainnet-beta
 solana config set -um


Anchor >0.30 introduced IDL changes and using it to fetch the IDL details will probably result in errors.

Switch to 0.29.0 which is the version the program was written with
avm use  0.29.0

Apart from fetching the IDL, as you mentioned, you have the option to build the program locally and get the IDL or use the Anchor Program IDL tab for solscan for quick checks on the structure -> https://solscan.io/account/CPMMoo8L3F4NbTegBCKVNunggL7H1ZpdTHKxQB5qKP1C#anchorProgramIdl

Yeah, Actually the link has IDL but it's separated so I had to build the program in my end.
Your answer is all correct!
